# Huge performance differences between sum(column_name), sum(1) and count(*) on a large dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

**EDIT:**
Since you guys suggested creating separate tables for player/tournament names and replacing strings with foreign keys I did the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tournament INTO tournaments FROM chess_data2
ALTER TABLE tournaments ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

I repeated that for namew and nameb, then went about replacing strings with foreign keys. Here is where it got tricky - I am not able to do it in a "legit" time.

I tried two approaches was the following:
1) Delete existing indexes
1) Create individual indexes for namew, nameb and tournament separately
1) Run the query inserting the data I want into a new table:

```
SELECT date, whiterank, blackrank, t_round, result,
(SELECT p.id FROM players p WHERE c_d2.namew = p.name) AS whitep,
(SELECT p2.id FROM players p2 WHERE c_d2.nameb = p2.name) AS blackp,
(SELECT t.id FROM tournaments t WHERE t_d2.tournament = t.t_name) AS tournament
INTO final_chess from chess_data2 c_d2
```

Unfortunately it was very slow, so I came back to user Boris Shchegolev. In comment, he suggested creating a new column in the existing table chess_data2 and updating. So I did it:

```
ALTER TABLE chess_data2 ADD COLUMN name_id INTEGER
UPDATE chess_data2 cd2 SET namew_id = (SELECT id FROM players WHERE name = cd2.namew)"
```

I started those queries half an hour ago, the first one was instant but the second one takes forever.

**What should I do now about it?**

**INITIAL QUESTION:**

**Database schema:**
date DATE
namew TEXT
nameb TEXT 
whiterank INTEGER
blackrank INTEGER
tournament TEXT
t_round INTEGER
result REAL
id BIGINT
chess_data2_pkey(id)
black_index (nameb, tournament, date)
chess_data2_pkey(id) UNIQUE
w_b_t_d_index (namew, nameb, tournament, date)
white_index  (namew, tournament, date)

**Problem:**
The performance of the following statement is very good (~60-70 sec. in a database with 3 mln entries):

```
# Number of points that the white player has so far accrued throughout the tournament
(SELECT coalesce(SUM(result),0) from chess_data2 t2
where (t1.namew = t2.namew) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament
and t1.date > t2.date  and t1.date < t2.date + 90)
+ SELECT coalesce(SUM(1-result),0) from chess_data2 t2
where (t1.namew = t2.nameb) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament
and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90 ) AS result_in_t_w
from chessdata2 t1
```

Meanwhile, the following select (which has EXACTLY the same where clauses) is taking forever to compute.

```
# Number of games that the white player has so far played in the tournament
(SELECT coalesce(count(*),0) from chess_data t2 where (t1.namew = t2.namew) and
t1.tournament = t2.tournament and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90)
+ (SELECT coalesce(count(*),0) from chess_data2 t2
where (t1.namew = t2.nameb) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament
and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90) AS games_t_w from chess_data2 t1
```

I tried a different approach (with sum) and it didn't go better either:

```
# Number of games that the white player has so far played in the tournament
(SELECT coalesce(sum(1),0) from chess_data t2 where (t1.namew = t2.namew) and
t1.tournament = t2.tournament and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90)
+ (SELECT coalesce(sum(1),0) from chess_data2 t2
where (t1.namew = t2.nameb) and t1.tournament = t2.tournament
and t1.date > t2.date and t1.date < t2.date + 90) AS games_t_w from chess_data2 t1
```

**Any idea what's going on here and how to fix that?** I'm using python 3.5 and psycopg2 in PyCharm to run those queries. I will be very happy to provide any additional information as it is a very important project for me.
**EXPLAIN ANALYZE** (Used for the last query):

```
Seq Scan on chess_data2 t1  (cost=0.00..49571932.96 rows=2879185 width=86) (actual time=0.061..81756.896 rows=2879185 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.161 ms
Execution time: 81883.716 ms
SubPlan 2
SubPlan 1
->  Aggregate  (cost=8.58..8.59 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=2879185)
->  Aggregate  (cost=8.58..8.59 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=2879185)
      ->  Index Only Scan using white_index on chess_data2 t2  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=2879185)
      ->  Index Only Scan using black_index on chess_data2 t2_1  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=2 loops=2879185)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 1
            Rows Removed by Filter: 1
            Index Cond: ((namew = t1.namew) AND (tournament = t1.tournament) AND (date < t1.date))
            Index Cond: ((nameb = t1.namew) AND (tournament = t1.tournament) AND (date < t1.date))
            Heap Fetches: 6009767
            Heap Fetches: 5303160
            Filter: (t1.date < (date + 90))
            Filter: (t1.date < (date + 90))
```

Comment: [data modelling] I would put the player names and the tournament name into separare tables and refer to them via a foreign key. That will make your table leaner, and the comparisons and aggregations (of the names) cheaper.

Comment: On other words: Read about *database normalization*, change your database to be at least 3rd normal form. Spare yourself a lot of pain in the future by doing that now.

Comment: "The performance of the following statement is very good (~60-70 sec. in a database with 3 mln entries):" oh... oh my.  Surely you're being sarcastic? 60-70 seconds is ***terrible***

Comment: Just a quick note: coalesce(count(\*),0) ... the coalesce is redundant, as count(*) never returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queries are performing poorly due to poor table design. From the EXPLAIN it is obvious that the database uses indexes, but the the indexed fields are all `TEXT` and the indexes are huge.

To fix it:

- create table `names`
- replace `namew` and `nameb` with `namew_id` and `nameb_id`, both referencing `names`
- create table `tournaments`
- replace `tournament` with `tournament_id` referencing `tournaments`
- reindex `black_index` as `(nameb_id, tournament_id, date)`
- reindex `white_index` as `(namew_id, tournament_id, date)`
- drop `w_b_t_d_index` unless you use it in some other query
- remove the useless `coalesce` from the `count(*)` query

Your query should then look like this:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM chess_data t2 
        WHERE
            t1.namew_id = t2.namew_id AND
            t1.tournament_id = t2.tournament_id AND
            t1.date > t2.date AND 
            t1.date < t2.date + 90
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM chess_data2 t2
        WHERE 
            t1.namew_id = t2.nameb_id AND
            t1.tournament_id = t2.tournament_id AND 
            t1.date > t2.date AND 
            t1.date < t2.date + 90
    ) AS games_t_w
FROM chess_data2 t1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed response!
I'll accept the answer when I'm done doing all this.

Comment: I was able to create new tables with player and tournament names but I can't seem to be able to perform step 2 quickly enough. Alter table in general is very slow, so instead I tried inserting columns into a new table:
SELECT date, whiterank, blackrank, t_round, result, (SELECT p.id FROM players p WHERE c_d2.namew = p.name) AS whitep, (SELECT p2.id FROM players p2 WHERE c_d2.nameb = p2.name) AS blackp, (SELECT t.id FROM tournaments t WHERE t_d2.tournament = t.t_name) AS tournament INTO final_chess from chess_data2 c_d2

Comment: But this query is also very slow and I'm unable to complete it. Any idea how to perform the second step (replacing names with foreign keys) more quickly?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE names (id, name); INSERT INTO names (name) SELECT DISTINCT namew FROM chess_data; ALTER TABLE chess_data ADD COLUMN namew_id; UPDATE chess_data cd SET namew_id = (SELECT id FROM names WHERE name = cd.namew); ALTER TABLE chess_data DROP COLUMN namew;` - just add proper datatypes, primary keys, unique on name, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but the UPDATE chess_data cd SET namew_id = (...) part takes ages :( I'll edit the question to add details on where I stand.

Comment: Well, updating 3 million rows may take some time... But I don't think you can make it any faster. You may try updating it in some batches (i.e. 10000 rows) if you feel like it will be better. Also, dropping some indexes helps.

Comment: Well at least then I could estimate the time it will take to do it, but I've never seen queries done in batches before, any idea how I should go about it?
Also, should I leave at least one index, e.g. when I'm creating the namew_id column perhaps it would be good to leave the namew index so that the subquery runs faster?

Comment: `UPDATE chess_data cd SET namew_id = (SELECT id FROM names WHERE name = cd.namew) WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM chess_data WHERE namew_id IS NULL LIMIT 10000);` - run it repeatedly until all rows are updated :)

Comment: Hey, that's great, what about the indexes? I can delete some but perhaps it would be good to leave the namew index when populating namew_id column so that the inner select runs faster,  what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122271/discussion-between-boris-shchegolev-and-johnnyq).

Answer (score 0):

The whole squeeze operation, (except for the composite indexes):

```
DONT CREATE TABLE games (
        id serial not null PRIMARY KEY
        , zdate DATE
        , namew TEXT
        , nameb TEXT
        , whiterank INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        , blackrank INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        , tournament TEXT
        , t_round INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
        , result REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0
        );

CREATE TABLE tournaments
        ( id serial not null PRIMARY KEY
        , tournament TEXT UNIQUE
        );

CREATE TABLE players
        ( id serial not null PRIMARY KEY
        , name TEXT UNIQUE
        );

INSERT INTO tournaments(tournament)
SELECT DISTINCT tournament
FROM games;

VACUUM ANALYZE tournaments;

INSERT INTO players(name)
SELECT DISTINCT namew
FROM games;
VACUUM ANALYZE players;

INSERT INTO players(name)
SELECT DISTINCT nameb
FROM games g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM players nx WHERE nx.name = g.nameb
        );
VACUUM ANALYZE players;

ALTER TABLE games
        ADD COLUMN id_w INTEGER
        , ADD COLUMN id_b INTEGER
        , ADD COLUMN id_t INTEGER
        ;

UPDATE games g
SET id_w = p.id
FROM players p
WHERE p.name = g.namew;

UPDATE games g
SET id_b = p.id
FROM players p
WHERE p.name = g.nameb;

UPDATE games g
SET id_t = t.id
FROM tournaments t
WHERE t.tournament = g.tournament;

ALTER TABLE games
        ALTER COLUMN id_w SET NOT NULL
        , ALTER COLUMN id_b SET NOT NULL
        , ALTER COLUMN id_t SET NOT NULL
        ;

CREATE INDEX ON games(id_w);
CREATE INDEX ON games(id_b);
CREATE INDEX ON games(id_t);

ALTER TABLE games
        ADD CONSTRAINT fk_games_idw FOREIGN KEY(id_w) REFERENCES players(id)
        , ADD CONSTRAINT fk_games_idb FOREIGN KEY(id_b) REFERENCES players(id)
        , ADD CONSTRAINT fk_games_idt FOREIGN KEY(id_t) REFERENCES tournaments(id)
        , DROP COLUMN namew
        , DROP COLUMN nameb
        , DROP COLUMN tournament
        ;
VACUUM ANALYZE games;
```