# Speeding up SELECT query response in large PostgreSQL Database (250 million rows)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

Using PostgreSQL, I have a very large table of ~250 million rows composed of the following 4 attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sim_values_english
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sim_values_english_id_seq'::regclass),
  word1 character varying(255),
  word2 character varying(255),
  sim_value double precision,
  CONSTRAINT pk_sim_values_english PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

I am trying to select the `sim_value` attribute based on the defined `word1` and `word2` using the following SELECT query:

(Assume I have 2 words: X and Y in which X or Y can belong to either word1 or word2)

```
SELECT sim_value
From public.sim_values_english
Where (word1='X' or word2='X') and (word1='Y' or word2='Y') and (word1!=word2)
```

This is taking on average 1~1.5 minutes to return the `sim_value` which is really long! Storing the entire table in memory is very costly since it weights more than 10 GB).

How can I speed up this query? What are your suggestions?

P.S.: `word1` and `word2` are never identical so if for 1 case: `word1` is X **and** `word2` is Y, Then there does not exist another row where `word1` is Y **and** `word2` is X!

NOTE: I have searched for similar topics but none of them addressed this exact issue. Thank you for understanding

Thank you

Comment: Do you have index on word1 and word2 ?

Comment: @Sylwit No I dont since these attributes are specific to that table and are independent of all the other tables I have in my database.

Comment: The fact that "these attributes are specific to that table and are independent of all the other tables I have in my database" is absolutely irrelevant to the question of whether you should have an index on them.

Comment: Create index as in answers bottom and join with values as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292297/are-execution-times-of-these-sql-queries-the-same/39292639#39292639

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39248443/905902 squeeze out the words and replace them by references to a words table (see my answer). And: you don't need a surrogate key in a junction table; you do need (two) composite indexes.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if you don't have it already, I would ensure that the following index exists:

```
CREATE INDEX ON sim_values_english(word1, word2);
```

Then I would try the following query:

```
SELECT sim_value
FROM sim_values_english
WHERE word1='X' AND word2='Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT sim_value
FROM sim_values_english
WHERE word1='Y' AND word2='X'
```

Comment: Can you explain the UNION because it will perform 2 SELECT queries when you can only do it with a single ?

Comment: @Sylwit The idea is that postgres will have to scan the index twice anyway, so at least you can avoid the creation of bitmap indexes and merging of bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

So you have to create index on these 2 fields

```
CREATE INDEX word1_word2_idx ON sim_values_english (word1, word2);
```

Then your query is very basic

```
SELECT sim_value
FROM sim_values_english
WHERE (word1='X' AND word2='Y') OR (word1='Y' AND word2='X')
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by **not** storing the **words**, but only **references** to them, this will make the bridge-table leaner:

```
CREATE TABLE words_english
        ( word_id integer -- or: serial if you want
                NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , word varchar UNIQUE
        );

CREATE TABLE sim_values_english
        ( word_id integer NOT NULL references words_english (word_id)
        , other_id integer NOT NULL references words_english (word_id)
        , sim_value DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0
        , PRIMARY KEY (word_id, other_id)
        );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON sim_values_english(other_id,word_id);
```

Your query can now be rewitten to:

```
SELECT sim_value
FROM sim_values_english v
JOIN words_english one ON v.word_id = one.word_id
JOIN words_english two ON v.other_id = two.word_id
WHERE one.word IN ('X' ,'Y')
AND two.word IN ( 'X', 'Y' )
AND v.word_id <> v.other_id
        ;
```

(or use a view to emulate the old table)

Check this older answer for a recipe for [squeezing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248443/905902) fat, repetitive columns out of a table.